# Normally Good FPS Skyrim all of a sudden has terrible FPS

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I've been playing Skyrim: Special Edition on Steam for a while, and I have not downloaded any mods. I log off the game after an ancient dragon fight. When I get back on a couple hours later, I have probably 1 frame a second. This has never been a problem before, I've always had a normal, good framerate.

Even on the "Main Menu", there is an incredible amount of lag. However, when I pause (esc), it goes back to normal. I have turned all my graphics, sounds, everything. The lag follows me all over the map, so it's not the area.
What's really weird to me is the fact that when I pause, the game runs smoothyl, but it's still incredibly laggy on the main menu.

edit: The skyrim launcher tried to read my hardware and set my setting based off of that, but failed. Just as it did the first time. It usually doesn't ask for this, it only ever did it the first time I played

Fixed: I deleted both Skyrim.ini and Skyrimpref.ini at the same time.

Comment: The automatic settings detection is set to that by default. The fact it didn't correctly register your hardware might cause Skyrim to be badly optimized for your specific configuration. The fact that the prelauncher did this again, suggests the original configuration files (*Skyrim.ini* and *SkyrimPrefs.ini*) have been altered. Did you change anything? Did Windows or Steam perform an update?

Comment: Are you on a laptop? Sounds like you switched from a dedicated gpu to integrated

Comment: I am not on a laptop, I have my own desktop.
https://lnv.gy/2YGQNj1

Comment: The auto-detection ran the first time I played skyrim too, as it's supposed too. It also couldn't find anything, so it just set it to low. That time, everything was fine. Steam has not updated, but I think windows has. I myself have not changed anything

Comment: Can you check when the files I mentioned were last changed? Their default location is 'C:\Users\username\Documents\My games\Skyrim\'.

Comment: Skyrim.ini hasn't been changed in a while, but skyrimprefs.ini was changed yesterday, between when I logged off and back on. So that's probably it.

Comment: I tried deleting it, I tried getting a copy of it from someone else, I tried everything it still doesn't work.

Comment: The PC you linked to has no dedicated gpu, so the performance wouldn't be great unless you're running on low settings. Make sure your settings weren't set to high or highest by accident.

Comment: I wouldn't think you'd ever get playable FPS in SSE from an on-board graphics card. The AO and DoF are huge performance hogs. Maybe try turning those off? Are "bSAOEnable=" and "bDoDepthOfField=" set to '0' in *SkyrimPrefs.ini*? If not, let us know if that helps. "bUseTAA=" and "bVolumetricLightingEnable=" can also be turned off. If this helps, I'll put it into an answer with more tweaks.

Comment: @SteptimusHeap same thing happened to me. I assembled a new PC, with the latest greatest everything, and Skyrim launcher could not detect properly (GTX 2080 TI) and set everything to low.